New Flutter User - Unable to Import Webview
I've created a new project in Android Studio.  Running it in the emulator does whats expected - the default program of clicking a button and watching a counter go up.
I'm trying to teach myself how to create a Flutter app using webview, however I can't even get past the first step of importing flutter.  With that default project, I just added the import to pubspec.yaml and tried to run to make sure that its okay.
WHen I run I get the following error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':webview_flutter_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/tjm/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /usr/local/android-studio-2024.2.1.12-linux/android-studio/jbr/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /home/tjm/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /home/tjm/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


I'm not sure how to even parse that, and googling the error gives me dozens of different suggestions and none of them seem to work or seem like overly complicated fixes for a failed import.
Is there a good way to understand how to parse this error and how to resolve it?
